# AlarmClock.ACTION_SNOOZE_ALARM is throwing an exception

Tags: android

The following code was written to snooze the currently ringing alarm. It is working fine in android emulator and behaving differently in different mobiles. Mobiles with API 23 are throwing an intent not found exception. Mobiles with API >23 are not throwing an exception, but failing to snooze.Please help me in resolving this issue.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    Intent a = new Intent();
                    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    a.setAction(AlarmClock.ACTION_SNOOZE_ALARM);
                    context.startActivity(a);
                }
            }
```

Here is the manifest file,

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest package="com.sriyanksiddhartha.fragmentdemo"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
             <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
             <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SNOOZE_ALARM"/>
             <application
              android:allowBackup="true"
              android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:supportsRtl="true"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
              <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
               <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
               </intent-filter>
              </activity>
              <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
               <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT"/>
               </intent-filter>
              </receiver>
             </application>
            
            </manifest>
```

[exception in mobiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMhty.png)

Comment: Still it is failing, I am getting the same exception.